# SQL - Select *, but add in another column as the nth column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is probably a stupid question, but if I **select tableA.***, but in the results I want a column from tableB as say the third column slotted in the middle of tableA's columns, is there a way to do this without manually selecting every single column from tableA and rearranging as required? This is in SSMS2016.

Comment: Try using some tricky JOINs.

Comment: No - either you use `*` and you just get all columns - or else you have to specifically spell out what columns you want in what order - no shortcuts

Comment: You should be selecting the columns explicitly anyway.

Comment: I take the lazy approach on this.  Select * from the first table and export to excel with the headers.  Rearrange the columns in excel, copy to your SQL window.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do that.

Just in case you didn't know, you can drag and drop table and column names within SSMS.  This feature comes in handy quite often.

See this for details:
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/the-dba-who-came-in-from-the-cold/2016/11/09/drag-drop-table-column-names-in-ssms/

Comment: How does re-arranging columns solve the problem of having a column from another table somewhere between the beginning and end of those columns?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 - type this into ssms.

```
select count(*) 
from tableA a join tableB b on a.someField = b.someField
```

Step 2 - start editing your select clause.   The intellisense (aka auto complete) in SSMS will reduce the number of characters you actually have to type.

If you type the columns in the order you want them to appear, you won't have to re-arrange them afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query

```
-- store column list of table1 in @cols1 with ',' delimited using sys tables.

declare @cols1 varchar(max) =  stuff((SELECT ',' + sys.columns.name FROM sys.columns
                        JOIN sys.tables ON sys.columns.object_id = sys.tables.object_id
                        WHERE sys.tables.name ='table1'
                for xml path('')),1,1,'') 

-- find second occurance of ',' and replace it with ',columnNameFromTable2'
declare @pos int =  (SELECT CHARINDEX(',',LTRIM(RTRIM(@cols1)), (CHARINDEX(',', LTRIM(RTRIM(@cols1)) )+1)) secondpos)
declare @finalCols varchar(max) = stuff(@cols1,@pos,1,',columnNamefromTable2') 

-- execute dynamic query to get expected result
exec('select '+@finalCols+' from table1 t join table2 t2 on (condition)')
```

hope this query helps you :)